# Constructor of structure error (calling constructor denconstructor of class, which fill the structure)

Tags: c++, data-structures, constructor

I have  the following structure:

```
template <class T>
struct Array{
    int lenght;
    T * M;

    Array( int size ) : lenght(size), M(new T[size])
    {
    }

    ~Array()
    {
       delete[] M;
    }
};
```

And the class(of objects which will fill the structure):

```
class Student{

private:
int ID;
int group;
char name[];
 public:

     Student();
     ~Student();

    void setStudent(int,int,char){

    }

    char getName(){
        return *name;
    }

    void getGroup(){

    }

    void getID(){

    }

};
```

Now when I want to initialize the Array type, I get the following in Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Domain.h"
#include "Student.h"
//#include ""

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"start:"<<endl<<endl;

    Array <Student> DB(50);
    Array <Student> BU(50);


    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
g++ -o Lab6-8.exe UI.o Repository.o Main.o Domain.o Controller.o
Main.o: In function `Array':
D:\c++\Begin\Lab6-8\Debug/..//Domain.h:16: undefined reference to `Student::Student()'
D:\c++\Begin\Lab6-8\Debug/..//Domain.h:16: undefined reference to `Student::~Student()'
Main.o: In function `~Array':
D:\c++\Begin\Lab6-8\Debug/..//Domain.h:21: undefined reference to `Student::~Student()'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: It's probably because you declared the Student constructor and destructor and used them, but you did not defined what they do.

Comment: Is that all the code ? Or do you have a a source file where you define the constructor/destructor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
class Student
{
public:
   Student();
   ~Student();
};
```

You have *explicitly declared* class constructor and destructor so compiler didn't define them for you - you need to provide their definition (implementation). In trivial case, this would do the job:

```
class Student
{
public:
   Student(){};
   ~Student(){};
};
```

Comment: Seeing what they do, simply removing them would have the same effect by the way.

Comment: @Morwenn Yeah, that's true. I wanted to show minimalistic example so used implementations with empty bodies.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have *declared* a constructor and a destructor of `Student`, but you are missing their *definitions*.

You can provide these definitions inline as part of the declaration of `Student`, presumably in the .h file:

```
Student() {
    // initialize the student
}
~Student() {
    // release dynamically allocated parts of the student
}
```

or outside your class declaration in a cpp file:

```
Student::Student() {
    // initialize the student
}
Student::~Student() {
    // release dynamically allocated parts of the student
}
```

As a side note, `name` should probably be `std::string`, not `char` unless you really want one-letter names.